# Run bash script with sudo, some commands as normal user

Tags: bash, sudo

I have the below script, it is meant to be run with sudo however the first to commands (The git commands) need to run as the user "ubuntu"

```
sudo -u ubuntu "git -C linux/build-repo pull"
sudo -u ubuntu "git -C android/build-repo pull"

uoa_image=$(sh linux/build-repo/make.sh | sed -n '1 p')

echo $uoa_image
```

However when this is run with sudo, the first two commands fail and the make.sh script when runs complains it doesn't have root

First lines give the errors:

```
sudo: git -C linux/build-repo pull: command not found
sudo: git -C android/build-repo pull: command not found
```

Comment: You should not build software as root. If there are reasons that you need to then a fakeroot will probably help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option:

Run the whole script as sudo-to-root and change the first two lines to use `su` instead:

```
su -c "git -C linux/build-repo pull" ubuntu
su -c "git -C android/build-repo pull" ubuntu
...
```

A second option:

set up root's PATH so that it can find the `git` command.

Comment: this fixes the git commands however the script still runs as if it doesn't have root

Comment: @richard has a good point in his answer; as to your comment: did you run it as root?

Answer (score 4):

The error messages are because of the quotes: you need

```
sudo -u ubuntu git -C linux/build-repo pull
```

not

```
sudo -u ubuntu "git -C linux/build-repo pull"
```